Tracing an electrical problem in the wall
My dad has a double wide home. All of the outlets in the front two rooms have stopped working on the outer wall,  including gcfi and wall switches. We had an electrician come and he said it was the outlets bad so we replaced every outlet that wasn't working. Still no power. He checked the breakers,  and everything looked good in the box.  He said to let him think on it an he will get back to us.  It's been a month and no response.  We have checked every connection where the home joins together and everything seems fine.
I was thinking that there should be a tool that would let us test/ verify circuits.  And there should be a tool that would help us locate a break in the wire if there is on inside the wall right? I've seen circuit tester tools , but then I've seen some that say not to use on a live circuit, and others say you can use on energized or non energized wires. Looking for any advice...thanks in advance.

A good tracer is gonna cost you a decent amount of money! But that electrician should have had one! One thing I would advise is find where the chain starts meaning if from the box there are a total of 5 outlets on that circuit find the first one and see if the connection loss happened there! Grab you a 35 dollar fluke pen tester (voltage tester) and start at the panel if there's power at that point but 5' away at the first outlet there is nothing then you kn9w the break is between those 2! (Careful to check the neutral cause you can have voltage but the outlet not work cause the neutral connection failed!

Not tooo expensive :) https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07VYN98QV/?coliid=IJRLQKPSM39WU&colid=2XAMAMHV3PE41&psc=1&ref_=list_c_wl_lv_ov_lig_dp_it

Most problems will be in the boxes/outlets.
With breaker off check each box for push in/back stabs connections and change to the screws.
Wire in wall problems are usually limited to nails/screws(recent,you did/had work done) or mice/rats, and rarer, but still possible.  Back stabs are known problem areas.
Did you change the GFCI outlet?  They are usually placed first on a circuit to protect all outlets pass them.  GFCI outlets can go bad and stop working/stop power to the circuit, and/or did you property reset the GFCI outlet?  Usually need the breaker on before resetting.

We did replace all the outlets, including the gcfi.  And dad does have a major mice/rat problem. They even chewed up the bottom inside of his air ducts. You can see the ground right through some of the registers.

@Daniel  Most people are lazy/cheap, so circuits then to use the shortest/easiest way to go from point A to B.  Think of A as your panel and B where there is no power closest to the panel.  That should be the section you find Kentucky Fried Mouse/Rat.  Inspection cameras use small holes.  If possible can place holes behind baseboard/pictures.
